How to determine if an observer can see an object with multiple mirrors?
How do I determine if an observer can see an object with multiple mirrors? I came across this image online and I am wondering if the observer (point O) see the object (point A)

My attempt:
I tried reflecting point A across KL, then across MN. Then, I traced from O to points N and M, forming a sort of triangle. Since the doubly reflected A was in the triangle, I deduced that A was able to be seen. But I'm not sure if I'm correct. Is there any tried-and-true way to figure this out?
Edit: I'm not trying to find the answer to this specific question, just if there's a technique or formula for deducing things like this out.

your way is the tried and true way.

Oh I didn't realize that...

Yes, typically we trace rays in the opposite direction i.e. from the observer outwards towards the object and we see if the object lies inside the cone formed. Indeed, this is the way it's done in modern computer games.
